# MapStruct: mapping two objects into one immutable object

Tags: java, mapstruct

There are 3 classes:

```
  class A {
     private final Obj x;
     private final AnotherObj y;
     public A(int x, String y) ...
     ... getters
    }
    
   class B {
     private final Obj x;
     private final AnotherObj y;
     ... other fields...
     ....constructor....
     .....getters.....
    }

    class C {
     private final Obj x;
     private final AnotherObj y;
     ...
    }
```

and a mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface CMapper {
    CMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CMapper.class );
    C map(A a, b);
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to have ***map*** implementation similar to the following:

```
C map(A a, B b){
  return new C(
    a.getObj() == null ? b.getObj() :a.getObj()
    a.getAnotherObj == null ? b.getAnotherObj() : a.getAnotherObj
  );
}
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Better to write your own custom mapper for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MapStruct does not allow mapping target from multiple sources. In order to achieve what you are looking for you will need to provide your own mapper. You could do something like:

```
@Mapper
public interface CMapper {
    CMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CMapper.class );
    default C map(A a, b) {
        if (a == null && b == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return map(a.getObj(), a.getAnotherObj();
        } else if (a == null) {
            return map(b.getObj(), b.getAnotherObj();
        } else {
            return map(
                    a.getObj() == null ? b.getObj() : a.getObj(),
                    a.getAnotherObj() == null ? b.getAnotherObj() : a.getAnotherObj()
                )
        }
    }

    C map(Obj x, AnotherObj y);
}
```